# How to get path of root directory of your project folder in Perfect 2.0?

Tags: swift, perfect

As you know for server side swift Perfect 2.0 framework is out. I was trying to get path for root directory but didn't have any luck yet.

**Snippet 1**

```
let fileDir = Dir("/Resources/fileuploads")
print(fileDir.path)
```

this code give me path as

```
/Resources/fileuploads
```

**Snippet 2**

```
let fileDir = Dir(Dir.workingDir.path + "Resources/fileuploads")
print(fileDir.path)
```

this code gives me path as

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projname-acxmbygsjkthxvbigpfoqesstidh/Build/Products/Debug/Resources/fileuploads/
```

However actual path where i want it, to point to is.

```
/Users/username/Documents/folderOne/folderTwo/projname/Resources/fileuploads/
```

where

```
/Users/username/Documents/folderOne/folderTwo/projname
```

is the path where my root folder of the project is located.

**Question**

how do i get path to root folder of the project ?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

After a long research, i found out that its unnecessary to get this location. the directory returned by Dir will be enough to store my files.

Answer (score 8):

This works in Swift 3.1 and above

```swift
// As a string
let THIS_FILES_PATH:String = #file
print(THIS_FILES_PATH) 

// As an array
let THIS_FILES_PATH_AS_ARRAY:[String] = #file.split(separator: "/").map({String($0)})
print(THIS_FILES_PATH_AS_ARRAY)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can actually use Foundation with Swift 3 and Perfect 2.

Next, to get your working directory path you will have to use **Filemanager**.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let currentPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
print("Current path: \(currentPath)")
```

In my case, the above snippet (tucked in a handler function) produced the following, when running from terminal:

```
./.build/debug/AltTabAPI
[INFO] Starting HTTP server on 0.0.0.0:8181 with document root ./webroot
Current path: /Users/rb/ProjectsSwift/AltTabAPI
```

Works on both Mac and Linux the same... Hope this helps.

Comment: is there something i need to change in Xcode's build settings. i am still getting the  path as "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projname-acxmbygsjkthxvbigpfoqesstidh/Build/Products/Debug" for the code 
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/webroot/apiCallTest") { (request, response) in
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let currentPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
    print("Current path: \(currentPath)")
    response.setBody(string: currentPath)
    response.completed()
}

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've already sorted out your issue, but if others (like myself) are curious about why you were seeing the `Dir.workingDir.path` discrepancy, note that if you build and run a Perfect project from the command line (from your root directory, `swift build` + `.build/debut/YourProjectName`), the working director will be your projects root directory.

However, if you build and run using Xcode, will be something like `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projname-acxmbygsjkthxvbigpfoqesstidh/Build/Products/Debug/Resources/`.

A bit annoying when trying to build a project that serves static files from Xcode, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with static files when building with Xcode, you can add A copy phase in Build setting to copy those file to the executable directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
```

to get access to folder.. code like below..

```
let  filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/image.mov")
```

Still you need any help feel free to ask me.

Comment: I don't it would work. because this is not Cocoa Touch. it's Perfect 2.0 (http://perfect.org) 
CoreFoundation doesn't apply here, so NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains isn't gonna work.

Comment: is there a way i can access $(PROJECT_DIR) or $(SRCROOT) from swift. without using any CocoaTouch Framework ?

Comment: I am only working with cocoaTouch but I will let you know If I found a solution for this. I dont know what is perfect 2.0